# .join() keeps quoting dictionary values

Tags: python, string, join, dictionary, format

I am using Python 3.4, and assembling a url to request a json object. But I am having trouble with using the .join() function to add key:value pairs from a dictionary into a string:

```
params = {'name.first_lower' : 'characterName'}

print("/".join("{!s}={!r}".format(key,val) for (key, val) in params.items())
```

What I need is for it to return this:

```
name.first_lower=characterName
```

But what I get is this:

```
name.first_lower='characterName'
```

Why is .join() or .format() giving me single quoted values from the dict?

Comment: Then why did you use `!r` here?

Comment: I just copied it from some example code I found online. I had assumed that the !s and !r meant replace with the first and second following values respectively.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `!r` format code calls an object's [`__repr__` method](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__repr__), which automatically adds the quotes.  You want to use the `!s` format code, which calls the [`__str__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__str__) method:

```
>>> params = {'name.first_lower' : 'characterName'}
>>> print("/".join("{!s}={!s}".format(key,val) for (key, val) in params.items()))
name.first_lower=characterName
>>>
```

Note however that explicitly writing `!s` is unnecessary because it is the default format code:

```
>>> print("/".join("{}={}".format(key,val) for (key, val) in params.items()))
name.first_lower=characterName
>>>
```

Comment: Oh, okay. I just copied the {!s} and {!r} from some example code, I wasn't sure what they actually meant.

Answer (score 1):

This has nothing to do with the `join()` method, but with the `format` method.
You are telling him to do so with the `!r` format specifier. Use `!s` or nothing instead:

```
In [1]: '{} = {}'.format('name.first_lower', 'characterName')
Out[1]: 'name.first_lower = characterName'
In [2]: '{!s} = {!s}'.format('name.first_lower', 'characterName')
Out[2]: 'name.first_lower = characterName'
```

Consider reading the [Format Specification Mini-Language](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#format-specification-mini-language) to learn all the functionalities of `str.format`.